# if loop repeating first if statement

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to create a continuous question loop to process all my calculations for my nmea sentences in my project. For some reason only the first `if` statement is executed. What am I doing wrong? I'm still fairly new to python

```
   if command_type == "$GPGGA" or "GPGGA" or "GGA":
        #define the classes
        gps = GPS()
        createworkbook = CreateWorkbook()
        convertfile = ConvertFile()
        print_gps = PrintGPS()
        #do the deeds
        createworkbook.openworkbook(data)
        print_gps.process_gpgga_data(data)
        createworkbook.closeworkbook_gpgga(data) 
        convertfile.convert2csv(data)
        convertfile.convert2kml(data)
    if command_type == "$GPRMC" or "GPRMC" or "RMC":
        #define the classes
        gps = GPS()
        createworkbook = CreateWorkbook()
        convertfile = ConvertFile()
        print_gps = PrintGPS()
        #do the deeds
        createworkbook.openworkbook(data)
        print_gps.process_gprmc_data(data)
        createworkbook.closeworkbook_gprmc(data) 
        convertfile.convert2csv(data)
        convertfile.convert2kml(data)
    if command_type == "$GPGLL" or "GPGLL" or "GLL":
        #define the classes
        gps = GPS()
        createworkbook = CreateWorkbook()
        convertfile = ConvertFile()
        print_gps = PrintGPS()
        #do the deeds
        createworkbook.openworkbook(data)
        print_gps.process_gpgll_data(data)
        createworkbook.closeworkbook_gpgll(data) 
        convertfile.convert2csv(data)
        convertfile.convert2kml(data)
    if command_type == "$GPGSA" or "GPGSA" or "GSA":
        #define the classes
        gps = GPS()
        createworkbook = CreateWorkbook()
        convertfile = ConvertFile()
        print_gps = PrintGPS()
        #do the deeds
        createworkbook.openworkbook(data)
        print_gps.process_gpgsa_data(data)
        createworkbook.closeworkbook_gpgsa(data) 
        convertfile.convert2csv(data)  
    if command_type == "$GPVTG" or "GPVTG" or "VTG":
        print('Better check $GPRMC')
    else:
        print("Invalid type:", command_type)

    list_gps_commands(data)     
    wannalook = input('Want to look at another message or no?')
    if not wannalook.startswith('y'):
        keep_asking = False
        print('********************')
        print('**mischief managed**')
        print('********************')
```

Comment: also change those 'ifs' with 'elifs', you want to enter the 'else' in the end only if none fo the above are true, right?

Comment: `if` doesn't start a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 if command_type == "$GPGGA" or "GPGGA" or "GGA":
```

use:

```
  if command_type == "$GPGGA" or command_type == "GPGGA" or command_type == "GGA":
```

or:

```
if command_type in ["$GPGGA", "GPGGA", "GGA"]:
```

Comment: Better to use the `in` operator, is cleaner

Comment: Like `if command_type in ["$GPGGA", "GPGGA", "GGA"]:` ?

Comment: Yup, just an opinion. And also you should explain why his solution was evaluating to true because of the truth value of a non-empty string

Comment: the 'in' operator worked! thanks guys!

Comment: Maybe explain why the "in" solution works ? :)

Comment: if command_type in ('$GPGGA', 'GPGGA', 'GGA','$gpgga', 'gpgga', 'gga'):

Comment: I've never used the 'in' operator this way but somehow it allows me to switch from one message type to the next when prompted.

Answer (score 2):

```
if command_type == "$GPGGA" or "GPGGA" or "GGA":
```

As you can see, here you are not trying to check if *command_type* is valued "$GPGGA" or "GPGGA" or "GGA". But if *command_type == "$GPGGA"* is true **or** *"GPGGA"* is true **or** *"GGA"* is true.

And a non-empty string in python is always true : your first condition will be evaluated true.

So you have to do :

```
if command_type == "$GPGGA" or command_type == "GPGGA" or command_type == "GGA"
```

Comment: or just `if command_type in ("$GPGGA", "GPGGA", "GGA"):`

Comment: You are right (not with "()" but "[]"). But I just wanted to clarify why the first condition is true.

Comment: what's your objection to my parentheses? Either a tuple or a list works fine here but it is probably more usual to use a tuple.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, my bad. I'm used to list in this scenario :)